# Why is Homebrew Day the first Saturday in May?

Tags: legal

The only reason I can find online seems to suggest that it is just because [AHA said so](http://www.blogaboutbeer.com/national-homebrew-day-is-this-saturday/). I seem to remember reading somewhere once that it was related to finally repealing parts of Prohibition that allowed for beer making by individuals at home, but I can't find anything about that.
Anyone have any other historical references or reasons?

Comment: I believe the end of Prohibition was today, April 7.  At least I've seen references to 4/7 being National Beer Day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a member of the AHA Governing Committee, the reason I know of is that it just is.  From the AHA website...

> On 1988, May 7 was announced before Congress as National Homebrew Day.
>   The American Homebrewers Association (AHA) created AHA Big Brew as an
>   annual event to celebrate National Homebrew Day around the world. AHA
>   Big Brew is held each year on the first Saturday in May.

Comment: I also found [this](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/homebrewing-rights/statutes/) on http://www.homebrewersassociation.org :
`On October 14, 1978, President Jimmy Carter signed H.R. 1337, which contained an amendment sponsored by Senator Alan Cranston (D-CA) creating an exemption from taxation of beer brewed at home for personal or family use.  This exemption went into effect on February 1, 1979, making homebrewing legal on a federal level in the U.S.`

Comment: And last year we finally finished making it legal at the state level.